# More efictive method of test large dataframe and add value based on another value different size/not merge

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, query-optimization, parquet

Lot of answers on merging and full col, but can't figure out a more effective method. for my situation.

current version of python, pandas, numpy, and file format is parquet

Simply put if col1 ==x the col 10 = 1, col11 = 2, col... etc.

```
look1 = 'EMPLOYEE'
look2 = 'CHESTER'
look3 = "TONY'S"
look4 = "VICTOR'S"

tgt1 = 'inv_group'
tgt2 = 'acc_num'

for x in range(len(df['ph_name'])):
    df[tgt1][x] = 'MEMORIAL'
    df[tgt2][x] = 12345
elif df['ph_name'][x] == look2:
    df[tgt1][x] = 'WALMART'
    df[tgt2][x] = 45678
elif df['ph_name'][x] == look3:
    df[tgt1][x] = 'TONYS'
    df[tgt2][x] = 27359
elif df['ph_name'][x] == look4:
    df[tgt1][x] = 'VICTOR'
    df[tgt2][x] = 45378



basic sample:
  unit_name        tgt1        tgt2
0 EMPLOYEE         Nan         Nan
1 EMPLOYEE         Nan         Nan
2 TONY'S           Nan         Nan
3 CHESTER          Nan         Nan
4 VICTOR'S         Nan         Nan
5 EMPLOYEE         Nan         Nan


GOAL:
  unit_name        tgt1        tgt2
0 EMPLOYEE         MEMORIAL    12345
1 EMPLOYEE         MEMORIAL    12345
2 TONY'S           TONYS       27359
3 CHESTER          WALMART     45678
4 VICTOR'S         VICTOR      45378
5 EMPLOYEE         MEMORIAL    12345
```

So this works... I get the custom columns values added, It's not the fastest under the sun, but it works.

It takes 6.2429744 on 28896 rows. I'm concerned when I put it to the grind, It's going to start dragging me down.

The other downside is I get this annoyance... Yes I can silence, but I feel like this might be due to a bad practice that I should know how to curtail.

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
```

Basically...

1. Is there a way to optimize this?
2. Is this warning due to a bad habit, my ignorance, or do I just need to silence it?

Comment: Have you looked into np.select ? :) Also your warning is right. You should use df.loc[...].

Comment: @IMCoins - df.loc[df[tgt1][x]] = 'VICTOR' ?? Did that originally and it just overwrote the first row and took forever to run... So obviously I jacked it, and it could be a combo of looping and loc not wanting to play nice...

Comment: @BeRT2me - I'm open to suggestions, but just saying that looping is not right doesn't help much... What is a better method to implement? I don't think it is wrong, just probably not the best answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given: (It's silly to have all `NaN` columns)

```
  unit_name
0  EMPLOYEE
1  EMPLOYEE
2    TONY'S
3   CHESTER
4  VICTOR'S
5  EMPLOYEE

df = pd.DataFrame({'unit_name': {0: 'EMPLOYEE', 1: 'EMPLOYEE', 2: "TONY'S", 3: 'CHESTER', 4: "VICTOR'S", 5: 'EMPLOYEE'}})
```

Doing: (Let's use `pd.Series.map` and create a dictionary for easier future modification)

```
looks = ['EMPLOYEE', 'CHESTER', "TONY'S", "VICTOR'S"]

new_cols = {
   'inv_group': ["MEMORIAL", "WALMART", "TONYS", "VICTOR"],
   'acc_num': [12345, 45678, 27359, 45378]
}

for col, values in new_cols.items():
    df[col] = df['unit_name'].map(dict(zip(looks, values)))

print(df)
```

Output: (I assumed you'd typed the column names wrong)

```
  unit_name inv_group  acc_num
0  EMPLOYEE  MEMORIAL    12345
1  EMPLOYEE  MEMORIAL    12345
2    TONY'S     TONYS    27359
3   CHESTER   WALMART    45678
4  VICTOR'S    VICTOR    45378
5  EMPLOYEE  MEMORIAL    12345
```

Comment: Same as Code Different's answer... Having played with both of them at length it continues to throw 

>>>TypeError: invalid entry 0 in condlist: should be boolean ndarray<<<

After digging I noticed it was because this is returning a 2d array.

So how do I get from returning a 2d array into something np.select can use without looping?

Comment: Although `np.select` is the more general answer, it looks like maybe you're using an older version of `numpy`, or have multiple `unit_name` columns or something... However, for this particular problem I realized that `pd.Series.map` would work just as well, if not be better. I've updated my answer @DanielRoy

Comment: Not sure what was going on, I looked every which way I could. I'm on current versions of python and numpy and no extra brackets were used. That being said... this version was flawless! ('''It took add cols: 0.02100086212158203 for 322591 rows''') Much better than anticipated, Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Flying blind here since I don't see your data:

```py
cond_list = [df["ph_name"] == look for look in [look1, look2, look3, look4]]

# Rows ph_name outside of the list will keep their original values
df[tgt1] = np.select(cond_list, ["MEMORIAL", "WALMART", "TONY'S", "VICTOR"])
df[tgt2] = np.select(cond_list, [12345, 45678, 27359, 45378])
```

Comment: Not missing much data wise, I'm using names as the p-key and then if True returning corresponding values from this function into 2 separate columns. data would look something like this... I'll add to my OG post. Not played with it much yet, but initially it is throwing me and error: 'TypeError: invalid entry 0 in condlist: should be boolean ndarray'. Ill play in it a bit though.

Comment: Same as BeRT2me answer... Having played with both of them at length it continues to throw 

>>>TypeError: invalid entry 0 in condlist: should be boolean ndarray<<<

After digging I noticed it was because this is returning a 2d array.

So how do I get from returning a 2d array into something np.select can use without looping?

Comment: Is `cond_list[0]` a 2D array? `cond_list[0].shape`. The other answer has basically the same idea as mine so no wonder both didn't work

Comment: cond_list[0] >> (28896,) --so cond_list produces 4 bool arrays, but if I understand it np.select needs it to be a bool array on its own, somewhere I'm not connecting the dots of returning the target...

Comment: `[(df['ph_name'] == look).to_numpy() for look...` may fix the issue here, perhaps older versions of `numpy` don't correctly recognize the Series shape? The other possibility may be if Daniel is putting extra `[]` where we don't have them, or has multiple `ph_name` columns.